# getting error while configuring crmsh for pacemaker for high availability

Tags: crm, pacemaker

I have installed **pacemaker** for 'High Availability'  on `fedora 18`.But did not get `crm` command for that.while i was installing  `crmsh` for that I am geting error during that configuration.

```
[root@localhost crmsh-crmsh-1.2.6]# ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
Our Host OS: /
configure: Sanitizing prefix: NONE
configure: Sanitizing exec_prefix: NONE
configure: Sanitizing libdir: ${exec_prefix}/lib
checking which lib directory to use... /usr/lib64
configure: WARNING: sharedstatedir directory (/usr/com) does not exist!
configure: WARNING: localstatedir directory (/usr/var) does not exist!
configure: WARNING: docdir directory (/usr/share/doc/crmsh) does not exist!
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... none
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking crm_config.h usability... no
checking crm_config.h presence... no
checking for crm_config.h... no
checking glue_config.h usability... no
checking glue_config.h presence... no
checking for glue_config.h... no
configure: error: in `/usr/local/src/crmsh-crmsh-1.2.6':
configure: error: Core development headers were not found
See `config.log' for more details
```

Answer (score 2):

Your system is missing the `cluster-glue` development packages.

On Ubuntu, this is `cluster-glue-dev`. `apt-get` install that and you should be good.